# R keeps date counting by status

Tags: r, date, if-statement, dataframe, apply

I am new in R, I have a data frame contain start_date, day difference and status, what I want to do is to use Sys.Date() minus start_date to check the days difference when the status is fail, and when the status goes to pass the date counting will be stopped and show the fixed day difference.

data.frame:

```
Start_Date  Difference  Status
1/1/2018    16  Fail
1/1/2018    16  Fail
1/1/2018    16  Pass
1/1/2018    16  Pass
5/1/2018    12  Fail
5/1/2018    12  Fail
5/1/2018    12  Fail
5/1/2018    12  Pass
10/1/2018   7   Pass
10/1/2018   7   Pass
10/1/2018   7   Pass
10/1/2018   7   Fail
```

So two days later, it will be like below:

```
expected data.frame:

Start_Date  Difference  Status
1/1/2018    18  Fail
1/1/2018    18  Fail
1/1/2018    16  Pass
1/1/2018    16  Pass
5/1/2018    14  Fail
5/1/2018    14  Fail
5/1/2018    14  Fail
5/1/2018    12  Pass
10/1/2018   7   Pass
10/1/2018   7   Pass
10/1/2018   7   Pass
10/1/2018   9   Fail
```

I used today Sys.Date(), so the pass status row will keep the days difference and the fail status row will keep on date counting.
I tired:

```
If (df$Status == "Pass") { df$Difference <- "I have not idea" } else { df$Difference <- Sys.Date()-df$Start_Date }
```

something like that, any advise ? Thanks.

Comment: @RonakShah thanks, I edited

Comment: Not clear to me how `Difference` column is updated. How is the calculation done?

Comment: the difference should be df$Difference <- Sys.Date() -df$Start_Date

Comment: For the first example, `Sys.Date-df$Start_Date` is 16 , how does it change to 18 then?

Comment: two days later, 19/1/2018 -df$Start_Date  is 18 and if it is passed, the day difference will fix the day difference

Comment: So just add 2 where `df$Status == "Fail"` ?

Comment: @RonakShah what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

If statements only assess the first element if given a vector (eg try `if(c(T,F)){print(1)}else{print(2)}` and `if(c(F,T)){print(1)}else{print(2)}`) so you need to look at them elementwise.

I'm assuming the Pass and Fail are set in another way and you just want to update the difference after the status is updated? If so, I recommend dplyr's mutate coupled with base's ifelse.

This changes the value in Difference if Status == "Fail" and otherwise preserves it as it was. You could also add a round with the difftime if you need integers.

```
df <- df %>% 
mutate(Difference = ifelse(Status == "Fail", difftime(Sys.time(),Start_Date, unit = "days"), Difference))
```